# Copying 2d arrays

Tags: c++, multidimensional-array

```
/* ... */
private:
unsigned char** a;
/* ... */
    void foo::init_a()
    {
    this->a = new unsigned short*[SIZE];
        for (int i=0; i<size; i++)
            this->a[i] = new unsigned short[SIZE];
    }
/* ... */
    unsigned short** foo::gen_a() 
    {
     /*
      *   Generating unsigned short** b array
      */
    return b;
    }
/* ... */
void foo::func()
{
this->init_a();
this->a = this->gen_a();   // Error here
}

/*... */
```

How to set 2d returned array from function to another array?
Functions `gen_a()` and `init_a()` well-working;
`memcpy(this->a, this->gen_a(), sizeof(this->gen_a))` not working.
Size of array a = size of temp array b from gen_a() function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you're doing everything yourself, you have to be careful to do everything. (A 2D `std::vector<std::vector<char> >` has a working copy constructor, it's automatic).

In this case, your 2D array is built as a 1D array of pointers to 1D arrays. You need to `memcpy` every 1D array.

Comment: Thx, I know about std containers, but I don't want using it.

Comment: Why don't you want to use std containers?

Comment: @mcuw: Why not? If not for learning purposes, there's no good reason for beginners not to use containers. And for advanced programmers, there's virtually never a real reason, too.

Answer (score 0):

Use the new move semantics in C++11

```
class A {
     A(A&& a);
}
```